# Encoding the content of a FILE in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

How to write a file in python so that all the content of the file is encoded in the form of secure hash(NOT MEANING FULL CODES) and I am able to decode the file and use the content of the file?

I am creating a project and I need a secure way to write a file which is encrypted and convert the content to non mean-able content.
And when I run my program I should be able to access the all the content of the files.

Comment: But hashes can't be unambiguously decoded. That's the point: two completely different values can have the same hash. If you want all values to encode to unique reversible values, then that's not hashing.

Comment: It sounds like you want a symmetric key encryption of your file's contents.

Comment: The problem with encryption is keeping the encryption key both secret and available for decryption.